# Serialize and Deserialize an abstract class to an escaped json string with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following abstract class:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(A.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(B.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(C.class)
})
public abstract class ABC {}
```

The class has 3 representations:

```java
public class A extends ABC {
   int attribute1;
   String attribute2;
   // getters and setters follow
}

public class B extends ABC {
   int attribute3;
   // getters and setters follow

}

public class C extends ABC {
   int attribute4;
   String attribute5;
   String attribute6;
   // getters and setters follow

}
```

I want to able able to serialize and deserialize the different representations into an escaped JSON, for example: if an object of A is as the following:

```
{
   "attribute1" : 1,
   "attribute2" : "string"
}
```

I want to be able to serialize it as :

```
"{\"attribute1\":1,\"attribute2\":\"string\"}"
```

The API for this implementation should not change from the default `Jackson` API, i.e.,
when I want to serialize an ABC object, it would be as the following:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = // init a mapper 
ABC obj = // init an ABC Object

mapper.writeValueAsString(obj); // would return the escaped Json.
```

When I want to deserialize an ABC object, it would be as the following:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = // init a mapper 
String json = // json representing an ABC subclass 

mapper.readValue(json, ABC.class); // would return the ABC object
```

**The solution should support having the ABC as its own standalone object/json and also when the ABC is an attribute in other class.**